# Proper Rails solution to manifest.json not existing on the CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6.1

When my tests run on CI, Heroku's specifically, they raise this error:

```
Webpacker can't find application.js in /app/public/packs-test/manifest.json. Possible causes
```

which I believe it's just because the frontend assets haven't been compiled. What's the correct Rails way of solving it?

For example, I found that if I add

```
"test-setup": "bundle exec rake webpacker:compile",
```

to my scripts for Heroku, it works, but this feels a bit like a workaround and not the proper solution. A proper solution would be something that makes Rails compile assets automatically when running tests, right? Something that doesn't depend on CI configuration.

The full error is:

```
  1) /friendships when logged in gets a list of friends
     Failure/Error: <%= javascript_pack_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track": "reload" %>
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       Webpacker can't find application.js in /app/public/packs-test/manifest.json. Possible causes:
       1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
          unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
       2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
       3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
       4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
       Your manifest contains:
       {
       }
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:30:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___487359012740265845_49820'
     # ./spec/requests/friendships_spec.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError:
     #   Webpacker can't find application.js in /app/public/packs-test/manifest.json. Possible causes:
     #   1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
     #      unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
     #   2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
     #   3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
     #   4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
     #   Your manifest contains:
     #   {
     #   }
     #   ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:30:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___487359012740265845_49820'
```

Webpacker is configured to compile in test mode (as default):

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  additional_paths: [ ]

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'

test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

staging:
  <<: *default

  # Staging depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

Comment: [webpacker:compile should happen during assets:precompile](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/webpacker.html#deploying-webpacker). Did you run `bin/rails webpacker:install` after adding webpacker?

Comment: @Schwern I did, webpacker is working on dev on my machine. I'm not running assets:precompile on machine and the tests run, Heroku doesn't seem to be running assets:precompile even though it detected it's a Rails project. And you are correct, if I run rake assets:precompile it runs webpacker:compile.

Comment: Check for differences between your dev and production environment configurations.

Comment: @Schwern this is an almost standard Rails 6.1, pretty much all the differences are the ones from creating the project. Production config shouldn't be affecting tests though.

Comment: I am suspicious of `public_output_path: packs-test`. If you start with a clean checkout (`git clean -dxf`, this might clear your master.key), does `rails s` work? What about with `RAILS_ENV=test`? Remember to always start with a clean checkout.

Comment: @Schwern: `public_output_path: packs-test` is the default in Rails 6.1. `rails s` works. `RAILS_ENV=test rails server` also works and compiles the assets on the fly I think. I did run `rake webpacker:clobber`.

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=test rails server` on a clean checkout of the application fails with the same webpacker error.

Comment: Tests on that clean checkout also fail with that error. So I guess this answers: tests do not work if you don't build the assets first and don't trust webpacker:clobber.

Comment: I don't know that's the answer, but it eliminates Heroku. Now you can debug it locally.

Comment: @pupeno how did you resolved this issue. My build is working fine locally but failing on travis